# Inequality involving algebraic expression of exponentials

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Given $0<\lambda_1<\lambda_2<\lambda_3$, $0<t_1<t_2$, $x\in(0,1)$, and
\begin{equation}
e^{-\lambda_3t_1}(x+(1-x)e^{-\lambda_2t_2}) > e^{-\lambda_2t_1}(x+(1-x)e^{-\lambda_3t_2})
\end{equation}
then is it also true that the following holds?
\begin{equation}
e^{-\lambda_2t_1}(x+(1-x)e^{-\lambda_1t_2}) > e^{-\lambda_1t_1}(x+(1-x)e^{-\lambda_2t_2})
\end{equation}
Based on the values I tried for the different variables it seems that the inequality holds, but I haven't been able to prove it. I'm looking for any suggestions about proving this or a counter example if this is not true.

Comment: I think that it should be $0 < \lambda_1 \le \lambda_2 < \lambda_3$. Otherwise if $\lambda_2 = \lambda_3$, the first equation is always true, however the second equation is not always true.

Comment: Good point. The values that I tried were all non-equal. I'll edit the question to allow inequality only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Proof**: Let
$$f(u) = \frac{\mathrm{e}^{- u t_1}}{x + (1-x)\mathrm{e}^{-ut_2}}.$$
From the hypothesis, we know that $f(\lambda_3) \ge f(\lambda_2)$.
We need to prove that $f(\lambda_2) \ge f(\lambda_1)$.

We have
$$f'(u) = \frac{(1-x)(t_2-t_1)\mathrm{e}^{- u t_1}}
{(x + (1-x)\mathrm{e}^{-ut_2})^2}
(\mathrm{e}^{- u t_2} - \tfrac{t_1 x}{(1-x)(t_2 - t_1)}).
$$
We claim that $\tfrac{t_1 x}{(1-x)(t_2 - t_1)}<1$.
Suppose that $\tfrac{t_1 x}{(1-x)(t_2 - t_1)}\ge 1$.
Then $f'(u) < 0$ for $u > 0$. Since $\lambda_2 < \lambda_3$,
we have $f(\lambda_2) > f(\lambda_3)$ which contradicts the hypothesis $f(\lambda_3) \ge f(\lambda_2)$.

Now, since $\tfrac{t_1 x}{(1-x)(t_2 - t_1)} < 1$, 
by denoting $u_0 = -\frac{1}{t_2}\ln \tfrac{t_1 x}{(1-x)(t_2 - t_1)}$,
we know that $f(u)$ is strictly increasing on $(0, u_0)$, and 
strictly decreasing on $(u_0, +\infty)$. 
From the hypothesis $f(\lambda_3) \ge f(\lambda_2)$, 
we know that either $\lambda_2 < \lambda_3 \le u_0$
or $\lambda_2 < u_0 < \lambda_3$. For both cases,
we have $f(\lambda_2) \ge f(\lambda_1)$. We are done.

Comment: Beautiful! I had spent the last 3 days on this problem without making any progress. If, in the future, I write a paper about the research that this was a part of, do you want an acknowledgement?

Comment: @ZaeemHussain   No, Thanks.